# Keyboard does not push layout above EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile

In my application I have the following layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/text"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/input_hint"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_hint">
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

When EditText is clicked, the keyboard pushes the screen up including the ActionBar so that EditText is just above the keyboard. What I want is for only EditText to come up sitting on the keyboard, but the FragmentContainer that is above remains intact "as background". I got some of this by using android: windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize" in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but my application is fullscreen and this tag apparently does not work with fullscreen.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I am aware, there's no way to achieve what you're describing.

These are the choices available to you for `windowSoftInputMode`:

- `adjustNothing`: When the keyboard appears, the window is not adjusted at all. This will stop your `fragment_container` from being moved or resizing, but will also cause the keyboard to cover your text input field.
- `adjustResize`: When the keyboard appears, the window is "shrunk" vertically. This will cause your `fragment_container` to occupy less space than when the keyboard is closed, potentially affecting your fragment layout.
- `adjustPan`: When the keyboard appears, the screen is "pushed" upwards. This will cause your `fragment_container`'s top portion to be clipped by the edge of the screen.
- `adjustUnspecified`: Allow the system to choose between the above three options.

Below are some pictures that (hopefully) help illustrate these attributes.

[image: Keyboard closed]

*The layout with keyboard closed*

[image: Keyboard open; adjustNothing]
[image: Keyboard open; adjustResize]
[image: Keyboard open; adjustPan]

*From left to right: `adjustNothing`, `adjustResize`, and `adjustPan`*